# Configure Network Host-Only DHCP Server segments with Parallels 11 on Mac

Tags: parallels

After upgrading from version Parallels 10 to Parallels 11, the company has removed the “Network Tab” from the preferences pane and changed my host-only network DHCP server segment to 10.32.x.x which broke all my exiting static host-only IP assignments. According to [this post](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/missing-network-settings-dhcp.329417/#post-775584), configuring DHCP is now a “Pro” feature meaning we are expected to either pay more or update all my existing static IP assignments (to 20+ vms).

How can you update the DHCP server IP segment to match the pre-upgrade state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a manual workaround, you can modify the *network.desktop.xml* file which Parallels uses to assign network adapter segments. Credit for this workaround goes to [Kevin01](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/missing-network-settings-dhcp.329417/#post-778233).

1. Shutdown/quit Parallels
2. Open the XML file with elevated permissions, in my case I have sublime configured in terminal, so I ran:

   `sudo sublime /Library/Preferences/Parallels/network.desktop.xml`
3. Modify the adapter settings located under "Host-Only". In this example I’ve set my network segment to 10.211.55.x

   `<VirtualNetwork id="1" dyn_lists="VZVirtualNetwork 0">
     <Uuid>{your-guid-id-here}</Uuid>
     <NetworkID>Host-Only</NetworkID>
     <Description>Host Only Networking</Description>
     <Enabled>1</Enabled>
     <NetworkType>1</NetworkType>
     <BoundCardMac></BoundCardMac>
     <VLANTag>65535</VLANTag>
     <HostOnlyNetwork dyn_lists="">
        <HostIPAddress>10.211.55.2</HostIPAddress>
        <DhcpIPAddress>10.211.55.1</DhcpIPAddress>
        <IPNetMask>255.255.255.0</IPNetMask>
        <HostIP6Address>FDB2:2C26:F4E4:1::1</HostIP6Address>
        <DhcpIP6Address>FDB2:2C26:F4E4:1::</DhcpIP6Address>
        <IP6NetMask>FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::</IP6NetMask>
        <DNSUseEtcHosts>1</DNSUseEtcHosts>
        <RegVmNameInEtcHosts>1</RegVmNameInEtcHosts>
        <EnableDNS>1</EnableDNS>
        <ParallelsAdapter dyn_lists="">
           <Enabled>1</Enabled>
           <Name>Parallels Host-Only #1</Name>
           <PrlAdapterIndex>1</PrlAdapterIndex>
           <HiddenAdapter>1</HiddenAdapter>
        </ParallelsAdapter>
        <DHCPServer dyn_lists="">
           <Enabled>1</Enabled>
           <IPScopeStart>10.211.55.1</IPScopeStart>
           <IPScopeEnd>10.211.55.254</IPScopeEnd>
           <IPReservations dyn_lists="IPReservation 0"/>
        </DHCPServer>
        <DHCPv6Server dyn_lists="">
           <Enabled>1</Enabled>
           <IPScopeStart>FDB2:2C26:F4E4:1::</IPScopeStart>
           <IPScopeEnd>FDB2:2C26:F4E4:1:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF</IPScopeEnd>
           <IPReservations dyn_lists="IPReservation 0"/>
        </DHCPv6Server>
        <NATServer dyn_lists="">
           <Enabled>0</Enabled>
           <PortForwarding dyn_lists="">
              <TCP dyn_lists="ForwardEntry 0"/>
              <UDP dyn_lists="ForwardEntry 0"/>
           </PortForwarding>
           <IdleConnectionTimeoutSecs>7440</IdleConnectionTimeoutSecs>
           <UseIPFilter>0</UseIPFilter>
           <ProvideIPv6Route>-1</ProvideIPv6Route>
           <NatDNSFilterIPv6Replies>-1</NatDNSFilterIPv6Replies>
           <UseInterface></UseInterface>
        </NATServer>
     </HostOnlyNetwork>
   </VirtualNetwork>`